# Using Start-Process to call a .bat file that calls an .exe, wrong path?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory

On PowerShell when I issue the command `Start-Process c:\Folder\install.bat`.

The batch file has this inside:

```
setup.exe /switch1 /switch2
```

When I run `install.bat` on its own, it runs fine. My problem is when I am calling it from PowerShell I notice it is trying to run `setup.exe` from the path `systems32`, and it says command not recognized.

How do I run PowerShell and give the correct path to where to run `setup.exe`? I tried to place a path inside the batch file, unsuccessfully.

Comment: `"C:\Folder\setup.exe" /switch1 /switch2`... anyway, why do you need the batch file after all? why not directly calling `setup.exe` from PowerShell?

Comment: Is the batch file located in the same folder as setup.exe?  I agree with @aschipfl.  Just use Powershell to run the executable directly.

Comment: The batch file could contain also `"%~dp0setup.exe" /switch1 /switch2` in case of `setup.exe` is always in same directory as `install.bat` and the batch file is used because it does more than just starting the installer. `%~dp0` references the drive and path of argument 0 which is drive and path of batch file with path ending with a backslash.

Comment: I need to use the batch file because it has all these switches that tells the .exe what to do. /switch1 /switch2 etc. It was setup that way as an enterprise solution. Mofi, I tried the %~dp0 reference but it did not work.

Comment: Wait I think `Pushd %~dp0
setup.exe /switch1 /switch2
popd` worked, let me do some testing!

Answer (score 1):

I guess setup.exe started with a path will miss some files present in the current folder. So this might be a PoSh way

```
Set-Location c:\Folder\
Start-Process setup.exe /switch1 /switch2
```

Or inside the batch change the current directory

```
Pushd %~dp0
setup.exe /switch1 /switch2
popd
```

HTH

Comment: I can't use the same switches on PS because there is a LOT and on PS it didn't work. This may give you guys a hint. When I run it off PS I get this in the beginning of the CMD window:  c:\Windows\system32>ccmsetup.exe /switch. When I double click the installer it gets me to the right path. c:\Deployment\Installers\setup.exe